# ¿ Como saber si todos los campos de un formulario estan rellenados antes de hacer un submit?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, css3

Tengo un formulario con varios campos en los que esta puesta la opcion 'required'.
¿ Hay alguna forma de saber mediante DOM si todos los campos estan rellenos antes de hacer un Submit?
Es decir quiero saber si el DOM ya contempla la posibilidad de indicar si todos los campos de un formulario han sido rellenados. No quiero comprobar los campos uno a uno con javascript.

Codigo HTML:

```
<form id="form1"> 
  <input id="campo1" type="text" required />
  <input id="campo2" type="text" required />
  <input id="continuar" type="button" onclick="formRellenado();" />
</form>
```

Codigo Javascript ( ¿ Suponiendo que existiera el metodo de form que te dijera si todos los campos estan rellenos ?):

```
function formRellenado() {
  if (document.forms["form1"].rellenado) {
    // hacer submit con una llamada a servidor mediante asp.net
  }
  else {
    // no hacer submit
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, quizas no se ha entendido la pregunta.  Quiero saber si el DOM ya contempla la posibilidad de indicar si todos los campos de un formulario han sido rellenados. No quiero comprobar los campos uno a uno con onchange.

Comment: No puedo preguntar en el chat ya que me faltan 20 puntos mas

Comment: @Popularfan los onchanges son los mas acorde para la duda, puesto que no hay ningun metodo de jquery/javascript que compruebe si los "formularios" esten rellenos o no

Comment: Popular fan, para el chat necesitas 20 de rep.. tienes de sobra :P

Comment: @Baker1562 mirare lo de los onchange

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas usando asp.net, porque no utilizas "requiredfieldvalidator"?

La idea es que tu le das el id del control que quieras validar. en este caso se llama "txt" asi vas creando uno por cada control que desees validar. 
Al dar click en guardar no te permitira avanzar si no se llena el campo.

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt"></asp:TextBox>`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="txt" ErrorMessage="Campo requerido" EnableClientScript="true" Text="(*)" />
```

Despues en el codigo solo llamas

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
 {
   // guardar
 }
```

Bueno si quieres javascript puro, puedes utilizar una función para llamar a todos los elementos con la misma etiqueta css. y los verificas por categoría. (Todos los textbox etc..) así no tienes que mortificarte por c/u.

```
 function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.txtform').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907198/jquery-make-sure-all-form-fields-are-filled

Comment: No puedo usar RequiredFieldValidator ya que estoy usando elementos html5